# What happened to the "Show In Documentation" option when you right click in XCode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Just got XCode 4, noticed they removed the "Show In Documentation" option when you right-click.  Is there a way to get this back?  Couldn't find it in preferences.  Doesn't seem like they'd take away something so useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you show the "Quick Help" Utilities view (cmd-opt-2) it will display information about the symbol where your cursor is; if it's something in the documentation it will provide links to its declaration, its class/protocol/framework documentation, and other stuff. Here's what it shows for NSString:

[image: NSString Quick Help]

Option-clicking on a symbol provides the same information, plus the little "book" icon will link to the documentation:

[image: NSString option-click Quick Help]